# Detecting Acute Angle Lines in a Masked Image using opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a project where I need to identify and extract the region of acute angle lines, resembling a "V" shape, from a given masked image. As shown below

[image: mask1]

[image: mask2]

and the required output is as below

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

I've attempted to achieve this using the following Python code to generate the masked image:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_f)
 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 
#range for red color
lower_r = np.array([0,238,132])
upper_r = np.array([25,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_r,upper_r)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)  
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=3) 
plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

However, I'm facing challenges in detecting the specific acute angle lines within the masked image. I believe there might be modifications or additional techniques required in my approach.

Could anyone provide guidance or suggest modifications to my code that would help in accurately identifying and extracting the desired region of acute angle lines resembling a "V" shape?

Any insights, code snippets, or recommended libraries for this task would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

[attempt1 based on answer]
I tried following approach based on answer given

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the image
img_f = 'path/to/your/image.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_f)

# Convert the image to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define the range for red color in HSV
lower_r = np.array([0, 238, 132])
upper_r = np.array([25, 255, 255])

# Create a mask for red color
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_r, upper_r)

# Dilate the mask to make sure it covers the entire object
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find lines using Hough Transform
lines = cv2.HoughLines(mask, 1, np.pi / 180, 100)

# Draw lines on the original image if the angle is less than 90 degrees
if lines is not None:
    for line in lines:
        for rho, theta in line:
            a = np.cos(theta)
            b = np.sin(theta)
            x0 = a * rho
            y0 = b * rho
            x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
            y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
            x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
            y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))

            # Check if the points are within the image boundaries
            if 0 <= y1 < mask.shape[0] and 0 <= x1 < mask.shape[1] and \
               0 <= y2 < mask.shape[0] and 0 <= x2 < mask.shape[1]:
                
                # Check if the intersection point is in the foreground (non-zero in the mask)
                if mask[y1, x1] > 0 and mask[y2, x2] > 0:
                    # Calculate the angle between the lines
                    angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
                    
                    # Draw lines in red if the angle is less than 90 degrees
                    if abs(angle) < 90:
                        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Display the result
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

following above approach i couldn't find any pair of line whose intersection of line lies in foreground, any modification or suggestion on this approach will be appreciated

Comment: You didn't calculate the intersection points. In your code (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are points on a line. To find points of intersection you need to first iterate through the combinations of pairs of lines not through each single line as you are doing. Second, you need to use the slopes and intercepts of both lines to solve an equation with two variables (x, y) which is the point of intersection. If the determinant of the matrix of coefficients is zero then the system doesn't have any solution and the lines don't intersect.

Comment: Also, another thing, I guess part of your code is from a code sample on OpenCV's Hough transform. You will also need to consider that you might need to tune the parameters to get the lines right. I once couldn't get it to work for me so I wrote my own Hough transform to make it work.

Comment: can you show me how to write own hough transform to detect lines ? i'm getting muliple lines

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it myself but you can do the following:

1. Apply Hough transform to detect the lines
2. Detect the intersection points of each pair of lines
3. If an intersection point is one of the foreground points then look at the angle between the two lines if it is less than 90 degrees then it is an acute angle

Alternatively, you can do the following:
For each foreground point see how many line equations it satisfies, if the number is 2 then it is located at the intersection of the two lines.

Comment: Hi , I tried to implement your approach as shown in edited question but I couldnt find any intersection point which is foreground points , was my approach same as you suggested?